# cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: python, ssh, kernel, spyder

Getting the following error on Win10 when trying to connect spyder to the remote kernel:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2010, in run
    self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2126, in _negotiate_keys
    self.kex_engine.start_kex()
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 32, in start_kex
    self._generate_key_pair()
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 53, in _generate_key_pair
    self.P = ec.generate_private_key(self.curve, default_backend())
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 62, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
  File "C:\Users\a010735\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

*** Failed to connect to 10.144.20.72:22: ImportError('DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.')
```

Comment: Did you get a way to solve it? I have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the same issue I'm doing some Necromancy on this question: 
My Solution is more of a workaround then anything else. I assume you are using anaconda since you mention spyder. My problem seems to have arisen form using pip to install pysftp into the anaconda environment. I had to uninstall anaconda, revert to my original python environment and there it worked without any problems.
Since I like spyder I installed it via pip into that environment...works so far